# Domain in gpkg QGIS

Tags: qgis, geopackage, domains, regular-expression, glob

I try to set the field domain for GeoPackage table fields. (description in : [see qgis changelog](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog326/index.html#id51))

I want but I can't use glob domain (with regex constraint), I try many syntax in pattern : '[A-Z]' , "[A-Z]", [A-Z]....Nothing

Does this function work or not yet? What pattern could work?
I use QGIS 3.28.9, python 3.9.9, GDAL 3.5.2

Comment: I don't think it is the regex error.

Comment: I use QGIS 3.28.9, python 3.9.9, GDAL 3.5.2

Comment: This tutorial also mentions it did not work, see at 1:41 https://youtu.be/xbJRszolLaA?feature=shared&t=101 So maybe a bug?

Comment: glob is not the same as regex and the syntax is different.  That said, your syntax is valid glob syntax and will match a value exactly one character long that contains one uppercase letter from the range A-Z. I've tested in QGIS and could not get this to work.

Comment: It looks like range, coded and glob domains aren't actually enforced. E.g. while having a range or a coded domain presents the user with a widget that restricts what you can type into a field (though you can type anything into a field with a glob domain), using the field calculator to set values allows you to enter anything you like into a field as long as its the correct data type.

Comment: So. Wait and see with this function.

Comment: QGIS offers this option, but it does not work. So you definitely should report a bug